# Drupal 9 How to add pager with entityQuery

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

We've a Drupal 9 installation and are trying to add a pager using the [pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) module for articles entityQuery, the aim is to list tagged articles in a tag page, but it’s not working. It returns `null`.

When we dump the data without the pager, using default drupal query, it returns the data of all tagged articles properly.
The code is added in the theme file `themeName_preprocess_page` hook and being called in `page--page.html.twig` template file.

Here’s our code:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('status', 1)
            ->condition('type', 'article');
            ->pager(2);
        $nids = $query->sort('created', 'DESC')
                ->execute();
        if($nids):
            $nodesNews = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
            $pathNews = base_path();
            $pager =  [
                'articles_data' => $nodesNews,
                'results' => [
                  '#theme' => 'news_pagination',
                  '#items' => $nodesNews,
                  '#path'  => $pathNews,
                  '#tag' => $tag
                ],
                'pager' => [
                  '#type' => 'pager',
                  '#quantity' => 5
                ],
              ]; 
            
            return $pager;
        endif;
```

And here is the code that calls the query:

```
<div>
{{ articles_data }}
    {{ pager }}
</div>
```

The above code returns only one page in the navigation and we’ve 10 articles, so given that we set 2 articles per page, the output should be 5 pages instead of 1.

Also `articles_data` attribute returns null. Could you please help me to find what’s wrong with the code? Happy to share more information as needed, thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with this module, but as far as i can see, the code seems ok. I guess you save `pager` in a variable that is used in the twig template

Answer (score 0):

Just reading the docs for this module [here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pagerer/blob/8.x-2.x/README.md#for-developers-rendering-pagers-through-pagerer-themes),
it would seem that you are missing at least the `#theme` and `#style` keys in your render array for the pager.

A more likely to succeed version of the above render array would be

```php
              $pager =  [
                'articles_data' => $nodesNews,
                'results' => [
                  '#theme' => 'news_pagination',
                  '#items' => $nodesNews,
                  '#path'  => $pathNews,
                  '#tag' => $tag
                ],
                'pager' => [
                  '#type' => 'pager',
                  '#theme' => 'pagerer_base',
                  '#style' => 'standard',
                  '#config' => [
                    'display_restriction' => 0,
                  ],
                  '#quantity' => 5
                ],
              ];
```